# Amount of zeros at the end of an array with recursions

Tags: java

I want to count how many zeros are at the end of the array using recursions. But I'm having problems with an array with all of it's elements equal to 0 because it's giving me the wrong answer.

I've tried putting the position in the range (0,v.length-1], putting one of the two conditions and not putting said range

Here's what I've done so far

```
public static int Ejercicio22f(int[] v,int pos){
        if(pos<=v.length-1){
            if(v.length==0){return 0;}
            else if(v.length==1){
                if(v[v.length-1]!=0){return 0;}
                else{return 1;}
            } else{
                if(v[pos]==0 && pos>0){return 1+Ejercicio22f(v,pos-1);}
                else if(v[0]==0){return v.length;}
                else{return 0;}
            }
        } else{return Ejercicio22f(v, v.length-1);}
    }
```

Comment: You say "you're having problems": **which problems**? What happens in that case? Do you get the wrong answer? Do you get an exception? Does it fail to compile? You need to learn to be **more specific** with your problem descriptions.

Comment: This code appears to be working for a few testcases I tried. What kind of problems did you encounter? Also show us how you **call** this method.

Comment: Ah I think I see where you went wrong: `v.length` does not change in your program. You need to check the value of `pos` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```java
public static int Ejercicio22f(int[] v, int pos) {
    if (pos == 0) {
        if (v[pos] == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        if (v[pos] == 0) {
            return Ejercicio22f(v, pos - 1) + 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

On first run, pass in `v.length - 1` as the `pos` argument.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of your current checks are ad-hoc: They work for specific edge-cases, but not in a general case. With recursion, there are two important things to have: a base case (where you stop recursing), and a recursive step. If we consider the problem on its face, we can consider starting at the end, with a base case being that we found a non-zero element:

```
public static int findTrailingZeroes(int[] arr) {
    return findTrailingZeroes(arr, arr.length - 1);
}

//Returns the total number of trailing zeroes from 'pos' or earlier
private static int findTrailingZeroes(int[] arr, int pos) {
    if (arr[pos] != 0) {
        return 0; //we found nothing in this step!
    }
    //TODO: Recursive step, which calls #findTrailingZeroes again
}
```

So now we have an algorithm which will start at the end of the array, stopping when it finds a non-zero character. Notice that "stopping recursion" is the same as not calling your own method again. Now, in considering the recursive step, after the `if` statement we know that the current position is a `0`. So, at least at this position, we knows there's exactly `1 + rest_of_zeroes` zeroes from here towards the start of the array. Further, `rest_of_zeroes` can be calculated (by definition of our method) via `findTrailingZeroes(arr, pos - 1)`, so that's our recursive step!

```
public static int findTrailingZeroes(int[] arr) {
    return findTrailingZeroes(arr, arr.length - 1);
}

//Returns the total number of trailing zeroes from 'pos' or earlier
private static int findTrailingZeroes(int[] arr, int pos) {
    if (pos < 0 || arr[pos] != 0) { //Notice the addition of 'pos < 0'
        return 0; //If 'pos < 0', then we hit the end of the array, no more counting!
    }
    return 1 + findTrailingZeroes(arr, pos - 1);
}
```

In the end, as you recurse over the array, you'll end up "counting" the zeroes:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Depth  Expression
1      1 + rest
2      1 + 1 + rest
3      1 + 1 + 1 + rest
4      1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + rest
5      1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + rest
6      1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0
Done
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to sum up anything. Just subtract `pos` from the `array length - 1`.

```
int[][] array = {{1,2,3,4},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{1,2,3,0,0,0},{}};
for(int[] arr : array) {
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr) + 
             " -> " + trailingZeros(arr, arr.length-1));
}
```

prints

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] -> 0
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] -> 7
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0] -> 3
[] -> 0
```

The method

```
 public static int trailingZeros(int [] array, int pos) {
     if (pos >= 0 && array[pos] == 0) {
         return trailingZeros(array, pos - 1);
     }
     return array.length - 1 - pos;
 }
```

Comment: I like it. More of a search than a math function, but still recursive. A bonafide improvement over summing.